# How to program an ARM microcontroller using JTAG?

Tags: arm, programming, jtag, swd

The JTAG interface is pretty new to me. I know most of nowadays ARM mcu's are programmed via JTAG. However what programming cable is usually used? I found this one, and I've seen some people use it in the past: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/275

But it is not sold anymore. What are other alternatives? Is it sufficient to connect the TCK, TMS, TDI and TDO of the mcu to the TCK, TMS, TDI and TDO of the programming cable, via a boxheader or so, in order to program it or is additional circuitry necessary?

I've heard there is something as SWD as well, but that's only for debugging not programming if I understand it correctly.

I am working with this mcu: cortex M4 TM4C1294NCPDT

Comment: https://www.segger.com/j-link-edu.html, if you fall within the license.

Comment: You already asked this question before, **do not repost**

Comment: Are you using [this board](http://www.ti.com/tool/ek-tm4c129exl#)

Comment: Also look at [this](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/arm/) you might find the answer.

Comment: I/we already answered this.  As your datasheet shows it is a cortex-m4 and that uses the arm swd interface.  Just get a board from any vendor (ti, st, etc) that has one of these frontends and use it.  they start at about $10

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have not done this but I have been told that this can be done.

The [EK-TM4C129EXL](http://www.ti.com/tool/ek-tm4c129exl#) launchpad board which you can purchase from here already has a JTAG interface build onto the board. I have highlighted the pins locations in blue/white. You can intercept this signals and route them to your board. This way you can use the JTAG interface on this board to program your part.

[image]

[Embedded Systems - Shape The World](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-world-utaustinx-ut-6-03x) free online course via edx.org uses [EK-TM4C123GXL](http://www.ti.com/tool/ek-tm4c123gxl). I suggest following the course so can get some help on TM4C1294NCPDT. Honestly it is much easy to just get a JTAG/Debugger as @Scott Seidman suggested. Also you might want to post your question on [e2e](http://e2e.ti.com/).

**References:**

- [Example files associated with the three books (ARM Cortex)](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/arm/)
- [Flash Programmer, GUI and Command Line - LMFLASHPROGRAMMER](http://www.ti.com/tool/lmflashprogrammer)

Comment: yes, can be done, that is why they carve out electrically the debugger front end, and provide a way (cut traces, solder bridges or jumpers) to isolate it from the eval mcu so you can use the front end to program your board or other mcus...

Comment: What if I want to program my standalone mcu with a separate programmer? I dont want to use my dev board to program my standalond mcu on my pcb. What programmer can I use and how should I wire it?

Comment: You can use a JTAG programmer like the one @Scott Seidman has suggested. Also might want to look at [Stellaris LM4F120 LaunchPad Debug How To](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Stellaris_LM4F120_LaunchPad_Debug_How_To)